# IntelliJ idea OS X weird color transformation

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, display

on OS X 10.11 and IntelliJ 15, all colors are affected by color profile set in Display preferences on OS X.
It is weird becasue on Sublime Text,  Clion and Webstorm colors arent affected, and I have the same monokai theme ported across them.
Do you have any solution for this? When I set profile to Apple RGB  colors are same in intelliJ but, I want to use my callibrated profile.

When using my profile and using OS X color picker, backgorund in Sublime is 39, 40, 34, and intelliJ they are 52,53,46 ( i.e. multiplied by ~4/3) but in IntelliJ preferences there is 39, 40, 34.

Could anyone tell me why it multiplies all colors by 4/3, and how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA 15 runs on Apple JDK 6 by default. Apple JDK 6 renders the graphics through Quartz, which applies gamma correction to the output. Newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA run on OpenJDK 8, which uses OpenGL and does not apply any additional gamma correction.